# Any hint for this :$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ 3ix}} {x-i}\ dx $?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have tried to get the closed form of this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{3ix}}{x-i} \, dx $$

using Euler formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, but I don't succeed. However, that integral is converge as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+e%5E(3ix)%2F(x-i))+,+x%3D+-infty+to+infty) in WolframAlpha which is

$$ \frac{\operatorname{Ei}(3i(x-i))}{e^3}. $$

Then any simple method for it?

Comment: It's weird the that is an $x$ in the formula, since $Ei()$ is a function on (a subset of) $\mathbb C$, not an operator on functions, and there should be no $x$ in the value of this integral.

Comment: Note that you are quoting the indefinite integral in the question. The value of the integral given in that link, which is what you are after, is $\frac{2\pi i}{e^3}$.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ 3ix}} {x-i}\ dx=\oint_{C}\frac{e^{ 3iz}} {z-i}\ dz=2\pi{i}\lim_{z\rightarrow{i}}(x-i)\frac{e^{ 3ix}} {x-i}=\frac{2\pi{i}}{e^{3}}$$
Where $C$ is the semi-circle of infinite radius in the upper half plane.